# Boostrap dropdown with items from database

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, dropdown

Im using boostrap and i want to populate a dropdown with data that is in my database. I already saw some examples but they always use a **form-group** instead of **dropdown** and use options inside form-group.Instead of doing that trick i would like to know if i can do it with **dropdown**. I know how to do my php to fetch the data from my database(php) and im using ajax too . Thanks in advance, **image to help**.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/prnbp.png)

Comment: if you return the data in json format and in the success function of ajax call you can bind the data dynamically as you preferred.

Comment: thanks , but i already solve it . I did it with php inside html.( i didn't need ajax since the data from my db is not changing).